# Pypdf: 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream' is raised when trying to update "Author" field in annotations

Tags: python, annotations, attributeerror, pypdf

I have successfully copied annotations from one pdf to another with this code:

```
def copy_and_update_annotations(src_pdf_file,dest_pdf_file): 

    #copies annotations from scr_file to a destination file
    reader = PdfReader(src_pdf_file)
    dest_reader=PdfReader(dest_pdf_file)
    writer=PdfWriter()

    first_page=dest_reader.pages[0]
    writer.add_page(first_page)

    for page in reader.pages:
        if "/Annots" in page:
            for annot in page["/Annots"]:
                obj = annot.get_object()


                writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=obj)

    writer.write(dest_pdf_file)
```

In the next step, I want to change some properties of the annotations, e.g. the "Author" field (obj['/T']). But this time, I get 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream' in the last line:

```
def copy_and_update_annotations(src_pdf_file,dest_pdf_file):
    #copies annotations from scr_file to a destination file
    reader = PdfReader(src_pdf_file)
    dest_reader=PdfReader(dest_pdf_file)
    writer=PdfWriter()

    first_page=dest_reader.pages[0]
    writer.add_page(first_page)

    for page in reader.pages:
        if "/Annots" in page:
            for annot in page["/Annots"]:
                obj = annot.get_object()
                if '/T' in obj: # Update Author
                    obj.update({'/T': 'NEW Author'}) #Update Author

                writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=obj) 

    writer.write(dest_pdf_file) # -->Here, I get:  'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream'
```

I tried different approaches like dest_pdf_file.encode() or converting the dest_pdfto an StringIO or BytesIO. Nothing worked so far. I am using pypdf-3.12.0 and python 3.9 64bit.

What am I doing wrong?

*** Update: When adding

```
    with open(dest_pdf_file, "wb") as output_stream:
        writer.write(output_stream)
```

I still get the same error. Maybe there is a bug in the package itself?
See the full error message here:

```
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_writer.py", line 1287, in write
    self.write_stream(stream)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_writer.py", line 1260, in write_stream
    object_positions = self._write_pdf_structure(stream)
  File "C:AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_writer.py", line 1306, in _write_pdf_structure
    obj.write_to_stream(stream)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pypdf\generic\_data_structures.py", line 369, in write_to_stream
    value.write_to_stream(stream)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream'
```

Comment: Hi KJ! Thanks for your Feedback. I updated the code like in the documented example but I am still getting the same error. See my modified code here:

.......
                    obj.update({'/T': 'NEW Author'}) #Update Author

                writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=obj)

    with open(dest_pdf_file, "wb") as output_stream:
        writer.write(output_stream)
     # -->Here, I get:  'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write_to_stream'

Comment: Hi KJ! dest_pdf file looks like this when printing: C:\Users\D\OneDrive\Desktop\folder\pdf\Neues Dokument - Kopie.pdf <class 'str'> also the filnames are  introduced as raw string to the def. An finally: the simple notpad example from you also produces the same error. I will now test if other properties than "\T" might work, eg. color

Comment: Also working on drive "C:\" does not work. The <class str> comes from me, I wanted to be sure that its a string.

Comment: Zvan looks to be correct, but I'd avoid going into the library internals like this. Can't you use the annotations property, and let it handle picking the right class to handle a string value? Looking for an internal keyword like "/Annots" is very risky. It could be changed in the next library update.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are trying to write '/T' with the type 'string', while actually in pypdf it is of the 'TextStringObject' type. You should cast the string to this type, for example like this:

```
from pypdf.generic._base import TextStringObject
from pypdf.generic import NameObject
#...
obj.update({NameObject('/T'): TextStringObject('NEW Author')}) #Update Author
```

Edit: also for '/T' you should specify the type 'NameObject', otherwise it does not always work

Comment: OP could confirm this by checking the type of the existing value before replacing it. But I wouldn't reference hidden internals. Just import TextStringObject from pypdf.generic

Comment: Yes it would be better, thank you. I updated my answer